# Change the default language for databricks notebook

Tags: python, scala, jupyter-notebook, databricks

I have a Scala notebook, but now I want the default programming language for a new cell to be Python instead. Is it possible to change the notebook in that way (preferably, in a way that doesn't require manual changing of each of the existing cells)? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can change the default language of a Notebook by selecting **File** -> **Change default cell language**.

[image]

See also [Set default language](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebooks-code.html#set-default-language)

As mentioned in other comments, it is possible to change the language of a single cell by using so called *magic commands*: `%<language>`

See also [Mixed languages](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebooks-code.html#mix-languages).

But they have some disadvantages e.g. you can't share variables between the different languages you use.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** You can override the primary language by specifying the language magic command % at the beginning of a cell.

The supported magic commands are: **%python**, **%r**, **%scala**, and **%sql**.

[image]

Note: When you invoke a language magic command, the command is dispatched to the REPL in the execution context for the notebook. Variables defined in one language (and hence in the REPL for that language) are not available in the REPL of another language. REPLs can share state only through external resources such as files in DBFS or objects in blob storage.

**Additionally:**

**%sh**

Allows you to execute shell code in your notebook. Add the -e option in order to fail the cell (and subsequently a job or a run all command) if the shell command has a non-zero exit status.

**%fs**

Allows you to use dbutils filesystem commands. For more information, see Access DBFS with dbutils.

**%md**

Allows you to include various types of documentation, including text, images, and mathematical formulas and equations.

For more details, refer "[Azure Databricks - Mix Languages](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/notebooks/notebook-use.html#mix-languages)".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I understand how to change the language of a single cell, I was wondering if there's a way to change the language for all cells, automatically

Comment: You are able to work with multiple languages in the same Databricks notebook easily. All you have to do is prepend the cell with the appropriate magic command, such as %python, %r, %sql..etc

Else, you need to create a new notebook the preferred language which you need.

Answer (score 0):

In a Scala notebook, use the **magic character** (%) to use a different programming language in the same notebook:

Cell 1 (Scala):

```
val k = "hello"
```

Cell 2 (change to python)

```
%python
print("hello")
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand how to change the language of a single cell, I was wondering if there's a way to change the language for all cells, automatically

Comment: Oh I see, I don't think so, at least I cannot see any options here, even when you clone it, there is no way to change it :/ Anyone else has more knowledge on this? :)